# ant runnable jar not working

Tags: java, ant, executable-jar

I created a runnable jar using **ant** but it is not running. when I run the jar I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/teamdev/jxbrowser/events/NavigationListener
    at com.MainClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.events.NavigationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more
```

but when I created jar using eclipse that jar worked fine. Menifest of jar I created with ant is as below

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909 (Apple Inc.)
Main-Class: com.MainClass
Class-Path: ./ commons-cli.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar commons-httpclien
 t-3.0.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ffmpeg-java.jar fmj.jar jdom.ja
 r logback-classic.jar logback-core.jar lti-civil-no_s_w_t.jar mail.ja
 r mp3spi1.9.4.jar slf4j-api.jar tritonus_share.jar vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
  xuggle-xuggler.jar comfyj-2.9.jar engine-gecko.jar engine-ie.jar eng
 ine-webkit.jar jniwrap-3.8.4 jxbrowser-3.3.jar jxbrowserdemo.jar log4
 j-1.2.15.jar MozillaInterfaces.jar runtime.jar slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar sl
 f4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar winpack-3.8.3.jar xulrunner-mac.jar
```

and menifest of jar I created with eclipse is as below

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ jniwrap-3.8.4.jar lti-civil-no_s_w_t.jar commons-h
 ttpclient-3.0.1.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar vorbisspi1.0.2.jar slf4j-
 api.jar ffmpeg-java.jar fmj.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar engine-ie.jar x
 ulrunner-mac.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar winpack-3.8.3.jar mp3spi1.
 9.4.jar tritonus_share.jar commons-cli.jar jdom.jar MozillaInterfaces
 .jar comfyj-2.9.jar jxbrowser-3.3.jar runtime.jar logback-classic.jar
  engine-gecko.jar mail.jar engine-webkit.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar jxbrows
 erdemo.jar slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar logback-core.jar xuggle-xuggler.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.MainClass
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

both are same and all dependencies are also inside the created jar but still the jar create with ant is not working.
I know you would recommend me to create jar with eclipse but I want to obfuscate my code that's why I am using ant to create runnable jar.

Comment: is your own class or not: NavigationListener?

Comment: "both are same" How are they same? They are completely different.

Comment: @Thilo: I mean classpath in both menifests is same.

Comment: "classpath in both menifests is same": `Class-Path: .`  versus `Class-Path: ./ commons-cli.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar commons-httpclien
 t-3.0.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar ffmpeg-java.jar fmj.jar jdom.ja
 r logback-classic.jar logback-core.jar lti-civil-no_s_w_t.jar mail.ja
 r mp3spi1.9.4.jar slf4j-api.jar tritonus_share.jar vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
  xuggle-xuggler.jar comfyj-2.9.jar engine-gecko.jar engine-ie.jar eng
 ine-webkit.jar jniwrap-3.8.4 jxbrowser-3.3.jar jxbrowserdemo.jar log4
 j-1.2.15.jar MozillaInterfaces.jar runtime.jar ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your jar file generated with Ant does not have `jar-in-jar-loader`, that's why it is not able to find classes inside embedded jars.

When you generate JAR with Eclipse you can Save Ant script, then `jar-in-jar-loader.zip` file would be added to project. Then use generated Ant file to create your JAR. This approach works for me.

**Your Ant script should look like this:**

```
    <jar destfile="C:\Users\\workspace\Your.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="org.mypackage.MainClass"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ libA.jar "/>
        </manifest>
        <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
        <fileset dir="${ProjectPath}/bin"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${ProjectPath}\lib" includes="libA.jar"/>
    </jar>
```

First `zipfileset` would include `jar-in-jar-loader.zip`

`fileset` would add all your classes

Second `zipfileset` would add libA.jar as embedded jar and same should be mentioned in `Rsrc-Class-Path`

Comment: +1 That's what I do. You just have to remember to regenerate or update that Ant file when you add or remove jar files.

Comment: is it possible to pass VM arguments like -d32 in this.

Comment: @Sandy, when building jar?

Comment: I think it is not possible to pass VM args while creating jar. I want to make runnable jar to run in 32 bit mode.

Comment: @Sandy, then run it like `java -d32 -jar Your.jar`

Answer (score 1):

With your Ant-generated Manifest, it is looking for the library jar files outside of the main jar file, the Eclipse one uses a special Main-Class and class loader to get to the bundled dependencies.

You probably want to use the [OneJar ant task](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant) (or something similar) to achieve something comparable to what Eclipse does.